# How to Find Appid in Developer Account for IOS App Before Publication

Tags: ios, app-id

My app has not yet been accepted by Apple and is not yet public although it has been uploaded to the the app store for approval.  I would like to get the appid in advance of publication for various purposes such as preparing for advertising and people have also requested it.  According to [this Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html), the form of the url is like

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8

Where the numericalpart is the appid.

How or where can I find the appid for my app in the developer account?

The appid in profiles has a prefix and the bundle-identifier and looks nothing like one of these numbers.

I also can't find an appid in the app part of developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in the URL when you view your app record on [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/), and it's also listed in the body of the App Information.

[image]